# Django ImageField save to locations

Tags: python, django

I'm able to upload photos to the media folder just fine. My problem is I can't save them to a specific folder on upload. I want the image to be saved in a unique folder based on an id being passed into the django view. Below is the code that throws the following error:

> views.py", line 90, in orderdetails
>       settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid) + '/' + image)
>   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Loop through our files in the files list uploaded
    if not os.path.exists(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid)):
        os.makedirs(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid))
    for image in request.FILES.getlist('files[]'):
        # Create a new entry in our database
        new_image = UploadedImages(client_order=client, image=image.name)
        # Save the image using the model's ImageField settings
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(image.name)
        new_image.image.save("%s-%s%s" % (filename, datetime.datetime.now(), ext),
                             settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid) + '/' + image)
        new_image.save()
```

If i just use image it saves just find in the media folder. Which is the code below. I know I set a folder inside my model with upload_to. Even with that I'm unsure how to set it to a folder based off of the ordierid.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Loop through our files in the files list uploaded
    if not os.path.exists(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid)):
        os.makedirs(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/' + str(orderid))
    for image in request.FILES.getlist('files[]'):
        # Create a new entry in our database
        new_image = UploadedImages(client_order=client, image=image.name)
        # Save the image using the model's ImageField settings
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(image.name)
        new_image.image.save("%s-%s%s" % (filename, datetime.datetime.now(), ext), image)
        new_image.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

After a night of searching I was able to find a fix. I had to define the Upload path with a dynamic function then set the upload_to to that function.

```
def image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/orders/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.client_order.invoice, filename)

class UploadedImages(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path)
```

This fixed my image location being saved to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate a string and a file object `'/' + image`

You probably want the name of the file here, so try `'/' + image.name`

That may return some additional path information, so you would have to strip that out to get just the file name.